# Работа с матрицей из 0 и 1

Tags: c++, алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант 24. Помогите пожалуйста! 
Программа должна находить в прямоугольной матрице, элементами которой являются нули и единицы, прямоугольный участок наибольшей площади, целиком состоящий из одних нулей.

Не знаю, как действовать. Была идея "попросить" пользователя ввести количество строк и количество столбцов - тогда их произведение будет равно количеству всех элементов матрицы. Задать массив с количеством элементов (это произведение).

Дальше циклом for( ) "бежать" по строке и искать нули. Если 0 найден, прибавляем площади значение один. Если найден рядом 0 справа S+=1. Когда в строке кончаются нули - переходим на следующую строку к элементу I+n, где i - номер первого нуля. А n - количество элементов в строке (или количество столбцов). Подскажите как бы действовали вы?

Все до чего смог сейчас додуматься - это по циклам считываю лишь количество нулей в матрице

[image: консольное окно][image: код программы]

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы **пытались решить их самостоятельно** перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, [отредактируйте вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/740450/edit) и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Пожалуйста, уберите фотографию кода и вставьте вместо неё сам код (чтобы отформатировать его соответствующим образом вставьте по четыре пробела перед каждой строкой кода).

Comment: @vp_arth, а по-твоему на фото не попытка решить самостоятельно?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что текст следует в виде текста, а не картинки в вопрос помещать, чтобы легче было его найти людям с похожей проблемой (Stack Overflow это не help-desk -- ожидается, что ваши вопросы могут быть полезны ещё кому-нибудь).

Comment: @Qwertiy, а сравнить время комментария и правки религия не позволяет?

Answer (score 3):

1. Считываем размерность матрицы `n` и `m`
2. Создаём матрицу `а[n+1][m+1]`, можно векторами
3. Считываем значения пропустив первый столбец и первую строку
4. Создаём матрицу `s[n+1][m+1]`, можно векторами
5. Заполняем первый столбец и первую строку нулями
6. Какдый элемент матрицы `s` должен содержать сумму всех элементов прямоугольника матрицы `a` от левого верхнего угла до текущих индексов

   ```
   s[i][j] = sum { q in 1 to i } of sum { w in 1 to j } of a[q][w]
   ```

   Но на самом деле обновляем так:

   ```
   s[i][j] = s[i-1][j] + s[i][j-1] - s[i-1][j-1] + a[i][j]
   ```
7. Делаем 4 вложенных цикла (t, l, b, r - top, left, bottom, right) и проеверяем, что сумма элементов этого прямоугольника равна 0:

   ```
   if (s[b][r] - s[t-1][r] - s[b][l-1] + s[t-1][l-1] == 0)
   ```
8. Среди равных выбираем с наибольшей площадью `(b-t+1) * (r-l+1)`.
9. Стоит изначально подвинуть `t` и `l` на 1, чтобы везде не вычитать из них единицу.